# User findOne not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have following Express route

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
var User = require("../models/user.js");
var passport = require("passport");

//User register
router.post("/", function(req, res) {
  console.log("user login post request");
  console.log(req.body.emailAddress)
  User.findOne({ username: req.body.emailAddress}, function(err, user){
      if (err) {
        console.log('post error: ', err)
        }
      else if (user) {
        console.log("already exsist")
      }
      else {
        console.log("here new user")
        User.register(new user({username: req.body.emailAddress }), req.body.password, function(error, user){
          if (error) {
            console.log("error -> Post request from user");
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            passport.authenticate("local"),function(req, res){
              console.log(res)
              console.log(req)
            };
          }
        })
      }
  })
})

//User login
router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/home',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' }));

module.exports = router;
```

The app is working perfectly fine before I added `User.findOne`, Just before User.findOne are two log statements which successfully log but afterwards no log statement logs anything in my terminal based on which I am guessing my programme isn't working.

Can anyone please help me in solving this error?

[Update] my `../models/user.js` is..

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose")
var passportLocal = require("passport-local");


var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

[Update]: Here is a github repository for the same: Here you go: github.com/irohitb/litifier-

Comment: post your `../models/user.js` as well

Comment: can you please share your models/user.js ?

Comment: @DushyantBangal check now

Comment: @SonaliRupela done :)

Comment: Could you try removing the passport plugin to mongoose?

Comment: @VigneshPT that will break lot of stuff in my code

Comment: @KuchBhi can you try to create a new instance from the model.
var userInstance = new User();
userInstance.findOne(....

Comment: code is fine it works at my end very well I guess there is some version issue I use for node v8.11.3
and for mongo db shell :v3.6.5
for Mongoose: 5.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the schema object:

```
require("../models/user.js"); // register your schema

var User= require('mongoose').model('User'); // load your schema
```

**Update from chat:**
If nothing is happening, not even an error, you are not establishing connection to the database.

Mongoose enables you to queue requests even before establishing connection to the database. As theres no connection, there wont be any response. It should throw timeout error after sometime.

Connect to the database using the following:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase');
```

Comment: This throws an error User.findOne is not a function

Comment: Sorry, require the model file as well, before you put this statement.

Comment: what should my schema be equal to here? 

`var User = require("../models/user.js")
var User= require('mongoose').model('User').schema`

even this is throwing the same error (TUser.findOne is not a function)

Comment: If I don't put anything then how will this line work `.model('User').schema`? Also, Tried the way you said, same error `User.findOne` is not a function

Comment: @KuchBhi, I've updated my code. Removed `.schema`. This should work.

Comment: @KuchBhi, replace your line 3 by exactly what I've posted. Baaki kuch bhi mat karo

Comment: it reverts back to the original error, Doesn't thow an error but doesn't do anything as well

Comment: Did that. Wait let me add my repository on github

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174621/discussion-between-dushyant-bangal-and-kuchbhi).

Answer (score 0):

I tlooks to me like your problem is that this callback function never calls `res.send`, `res.end` or `next()`:

```
router.post("/", function(req, res) {})
```

This function, although it is anonymous (doesn't have a name) is a piece of Express [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

Each piece of middleware must either call `res.send`, `res.end` *or* `next()` otherwise the middleware will hang:

> If the current middleware function does not end the request-response cycle, it must call next() to pass control to the next middleware function. Otherwise, the request will be left hanging.